How do I get Responsive Control values in Elementor, where 'selectors' => [] method can't be used?
I'm developing a custom elementor widget, and I'm trying to set font-variation-settings which includes weight and optical size. Please note that, I can NOT set weight using font-weight property and then set optical-size individually as a single attribute under font-variation-settings using 'selectors' => [] method, so that's not a solution. The font-variation-settings may later have more attributes, and all ofc need to written as a single css property.
Now, the problem I'm getting is that I couldn't set responsive font-variation-settings, the desktop values are getting applied for tablet and mobile as well. It's just not working. So, how I get values for such controls where 'selectors' => [] method can't be used?
Here's my code:
1. Weight Control (WGHT)
$this->add_responsive_control(
    'weight',
    [
        'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::SLIDER,
        'label' => esc_html__('Weight', 'textdomain'),
        'size_units' => ['px', '%', 'em', 'rem'],
        'range' => [
            'px' => [
                'min' => 100,
                'max' => 700,
                'step' => 100,
            ],
        ],
        'devices' => ['desktop', 'tablet', 'mobile'],
        'default' => [
            'size' => 400,
            'unit' => 'px',
        ],
    ]
);

2. Optical Size Control (OPSZ)
$this->add_responsive_control(
    'optical_size',
    [
        'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::SLIDER,
        'label' => esc_html__('Optical Size', 'textdomain'),
        'size_units' => ['px', '%', 'em', 'rem'],
        'range' => [
            'px' => [
                'min' => 10,
                'max' => 100,
                'step' => 10,
            ],
        ],
        'devices' => ['desktop', 'tablet', 'mobile'],
        'default' => [
            'size' => 16,
            'unit' => 'px',
        ],
    ]
);

3. Rendering the text
protected function render() {
    $settings = $this->get_settings_for_display();

    $weight = $settings['weight']['size'];
    $optical_size = $settings['optical_size']['size'];

    echo '<span style="font-variation-settings: \'wght\' ' . esc_attr($weight) . ', \'opsz\' ' . esc_attr($optical_size) . ';">Sample Text</span>';
}

Well, I looked at Elementor Docs, and there is this -
Elementor Docs > Responsive Data
So, there is no information, and it's WIP since 2023.
